# mudtab - how to fix the tab panels position:fixed

Tags: mudblazor

How to make the mudtab fixed at the same position. if the contents are scrolled it should be fixed at the top and not moving.

want to make the position: fixed.

I tried doing this adding position: fixed.

How ever when i try to add this attribute it doesnot work.
any body can help?

Here is the sample code:

```
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet
```

Comment: you're missing the sample code.

Comment: I have similar issues - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77273964/how-to-fix-the-mudtabpanel-when-scrolling